# Adding date last modified to file name with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, date

For my work I have to rename a lot of files to include the date when it was last modified. I found I can do this with PowerShell.

However how can I run this script? I do not have a lot of experience with PS. Thanks.

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\Coolblue"
set "Target=C:\Coolblue_out"
PowerShell -Nop -C "Get-ChildItem '%Source%\*.csv'|Copy-Item -Destination {'%Target%\{0} {1:MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss}.csv' -f $_.BaseName,$_.LastWriteTime} -WhatIf"
```

Comment: Open `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`, then type `C:\path\to\script.bat` and hit the enter key

Comment: Why do that?  `dir | select name, lastwritetime`

Answer (score 0):

Why run PowerShell from a cmd box and not directly in PowerShell?

```
$Source = 'C:\Coolblue'
$Target = 'C:\Coolblue_out'

# make sure the destination path exists
$null = New-Item -Path $Target -ItemType Directory -Force

# rename the csv files
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.csv' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # combine the targetfolder with the new file name
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $Target -ChildPath ('{0} {1:MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss}.csv' -f $_.BaseName, $_.LastWriteTime)
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $newFile -WhatIf
}
```

If you need the code to also process files in subfolders of `$Source` and maintain the folder structure in the `$Target` folder, do this:

```
$Source = 'C:\Coolblue'
$Target = 'C:\Coolblue_out'

# rename the csv files
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.csv' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $Target -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($Source.Length)
    # make sure the destination path exists
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    # combine the targetfolder with the new file name
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath ('{0} {1:MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss}.csv' -f $_.BaseName, $_.LastWriteTime)
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $newFile -WhatIf
}
```

In both cases, if you are happy with what `-WhatIf` shows you in the console what *WOULD* be copied, remove that `-WhatIf` switch and run the code again to actually start copying.